# Can't resize UIImageView's frame in subclassed UITableViewCell with dynamic height

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

In my `UITableView`, all the cells will be a different height. All of them have a background image, which is a bubble picture. All of the cell's `TextLabels` need to be different widths as well, so I've subclassed `UITableViewCell` and have given it two properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel* messageTextLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView* bubbleImageView;
```

I have my custom `UITableViewCell`'s initWithStyle set up like so:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {

    //stretchable bubble image
    UIImage *rawBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"text_bubble"];
    UIImage *background = [rawBackground stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:13 topCapHeight:22];
    _bubbleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];

     //textlabel
    _messageTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [_messageTextLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
    [_messageTextLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [_messageTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [_messageTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [self.contentView addSubview:_bubbleImageView];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_messageTextLabel];

}
    return self;
}
```

In my TableView's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I've already tried to just alloc a `UIImageView` there and set it to the cell's frame, and that works, but when I scroll up and down then the screen gets cluttered with `UIImageViews` being re-alloced over and over. I've tried the if(cell == nil) technique, but that just makes my entire `UITableView` blank. So, this is what I have right now:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    Cell *cell = (Cell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //works just fine
    [cell.messageTextLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 245, cell.frame.size.height -10)];

    //this doesn't work at all
    [cell.bubbleImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];

    [cell.messageTextLabel setText:[self.randomData objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

    return cell;
}
```

So my `UITableView` ends up looking like this when run (cell selected so you can see the frame):

[image]

Note that I can set the frame of the `bubbleImageView` in my `UITableViewCell` subclass, but I don't know what the cell's height is going to be then. I'm more baffled by the fact that I can set my `messageTextLabel`'s frame and not my bubbleImageViews. I may be doing something that is very elementary wrong, it's a simple problem though for some reason I'm getting tripped up.

Thank you!

Comment: I have the answer to your problem but i need a few questions answered. Are you using xibs or prototype cells?

Comment: I'm using a storyboard with a UIViewController in which I instantiate a UITableView programatically in viewDidLoad

Comment: So there are no prototype cells, since that is a feature of having the tableview in the storyboard. Next question, is the label important? This seems like a text view would be more appropriate for how you want to display the text.

Comment: It doesn't matter either way, just using a label make it more complicated to calculate the proper height.

Comment: This question is important though, is this for iOS 7.0 or before that?

Comment: I need to use another UILabel because I can't manipulate the width of a standard UITableViewCell's textLabel. And also this is for iOS 7. Thank you!

Comment: Due to the fact you are allocating a new label and adding it as a subview, means that you just want to display text in a cell. That is correct? If so, then what holds the text becomes irrelevant, because all text displaying objects can be formatted the same and look the same, but textView has methods to figure out text height that doesn't involve tricky viewing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen 2 problems here:

- I think that you have the auto-layout enabled.
  In this case the initial frame and the autoresizingMask are translated to auto-layout constraints automatically.
  After this no frame changes will change the view's size and location - only the constraints...
- You haven't set the `contentMode` of the image view to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` (this is the default, but it's better define this kind of properties anyway).
  Just add this line: `_bubbleImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;` right after its initiation.

I think that the solution here is auto-layout - setting constraints properly will solve this issue.
I suggest doing it in the storyboard, with table view controller and dynamic cells...

Comment: You're the man, thanks. I had to disable autoresizingMask after the UIImageView's initialization and then had to set the contentMode.